# Jenkins enable text box when check box is selected

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Can you please help me on how I can enable/disable a text box area based on checkbox status in Jenkins.
Example: I have a checkbox called "build". If "build" is selected only than the text box area should be available for the user to enter the build number. The text box is a user input box.

Comment: please provide some code samples what you tried so far, so its better to help on existing code snippets than "out-of-the-box".

Comment: Im not sure you can achieve this without changing jenkins code. What you can do is not use the text box value if the checkbox has not been selected.

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable through a plugin named "active choices". You can take a look at it's features and documentation here: https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/